# Different behavior when setting attribute from HTML compared to JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prevent Chrome from showing auto fill dropdown on incorrect text boxes and found that one workaround is to set the `autocomplete` attribute to `one-time-code`.

This prevents the auto fill/dropdown from appearing if I put this attribute in the HTML template directly...

```
<input type=“text” ... autocomplete=“one-time-code” />
```

...but doesn’t work if I use the following JS code to set it globally for all text boxes:

```
$(document).on(“focus”, “input”, function() {
    this.setAttribute(“autocomplete”, “one-time-code”);
});
```

I see at runtime that the attribute gets added to the input elements, but it no longer disables the auto fill/dropdown on those elements (the way the HTML edit did).

Why would the behavior be different when I modify the HTML template compared to when I do it through JavaScript? Is there any way to make it work through JS as well?

Comment: One thing to do would be to use straight quotes instead of so-called smart quotes (which usually cause syntax errors in programming)

Comment: try this, `$(this).attr('autocomplete', "one-time-code");`

Comment: Fixing the syntax errors, your original `<input type=“text” ... autocomplete=“one-time-code” />` doesn't prevent autocomplete for me, at least in Chrome. `one-time-code` doesn't seem to do anything. `off` works, though, and so does `this.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');`

Comment: The quotes may be looking off due to copy-paste, but syntax errors aren’t there (if they were there, then the autocomplete attribute wouldn’t show up on all elements that the JS code touches). I have the exact opposite of your results, “off” doesn’t prevent the autocomplete, but “one-time-code” does. I’m on Chrome 89.0.4389.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a matter of when the event handlers run vs when the browser tries to actually populate the fields.  Run the snippet below... you'll notice that the focus event that fires on "input" doesn't run unless you actually click into a text box...  whereas the focus event that fires on null runs any time you click out of the window and then back into the window...  if you don't click in the box itself, but just click the up arrow you can set the value to 5... if you then click into the box the on focus "input" event is handled and the input is flagged as invalid...

My guess is that your focus event is firing after autocomplete fills the boxes... consider using an onFocus with null trigger instead of input and then select all your input boxes from within the handling function as I did in the snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('In Document.Ready');
  $(document).on("focus", null, function() {
    console.log('Focus on Document with Null Selector');
    $('input').each(function(index) {
      this.setAttribute("max", "5");

    })
  });
  $(document).on("focus", "input", function() {
    console.log('Focus on Document with Input Selector');
    this.setAttribute("max", "3");
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="5">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```